# How do I use an object from a CDN in a local javascript file?

Tags: javascript, regression

I am attempting to use regression.js in a local javascript file. I am using a CDN to get regression.js.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regression/1.4.0/regression.min.js'></script>
```

When I attempt to use regression in my local javascript file,

```
``data is an array of coordinate pairs, similar to the example [here](https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js)
let linearRegression = regression.linear(data);
```

however then when I try to display the regression equation I get an error. I Have figured out that regression is seen as a function, but I am not sure why. Does anybody know how I can use the regression js methods, when I am using the cdn?

```
<head>
        <!--MetaData-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Security History</title>
        <!--Stylesheets-->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "interface/common.css" %}' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "interface/edit_style.css" %}' />
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/popper.min.js'></script>-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regression/1.4.0/regression.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src='{% static "interface/historyGraphing.js" %}'></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Could you please post a full setup with your html and everything?

Comment: I don't think that more than the head is necessary, but if you need more, ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library, but it appears as though you're expected to use it like this on the web:

```js
let linearRegression = regression('linear', [[0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]]);

console.log(linearRegression)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regression/1.4.0/regression.min.js'></script>
```

Their docs reference the CDN-hosted library, but they aren't 100% clear. The latest CDN-hosted version of the library is version 1.4.0. If you take a look at [the 1.4.0 docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regression/v/1.4.0), they provide examples like mine above.

The [docs that you likely found](https://github.com/tom-alexander/regression-js) for the latest release (2.0.1) assume that you'll be importing the module.

Comment: Thank You! Where in the documentation did you find this?, or if not in the documentation, then where?

Comment: Also, do you have any other recommendations for regression analysis libraries?

Comment: @wilmoskal - I've updated the answer with more information. I can't speak to regression analysis libraries. That's a topic I'm not familiar with.